# I work (in) downtown

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct to say?

> 1. I work **in** downtown.
> 2. I work downtown.

Comment: You work downtown.

Comment: The normal usage is ***I work downtown***.

Answer (score 2):

- **I work downtown** is the correct way.

As an adverb **downtown** means *in or into the downtown area of a city*

You can use as a noun - **I work in the downtown.** and as an adjective too - **I work in the downtown area**.

Answer (score 0):

*Downtown* is actually a [noun, an adverb and an adjective](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/downtown), it is not a preposition. Your sentence uses *downtown* as an adverb, so using *in downtown* is grammatically incorrect.
You could say "I work in the downtown area" because in this case *downtown* is an adjective describing the area.

Comment: Since it may be used as a noun, what's wrong with "I work in the downtown"?

Answer (score 0):

*I work downtown* means you regularly travel to the downtown area of a city to work.

*I work in downtown* means the "border" that separates downtown from not-downtown is important.  You might say this if you are talking to someone in the city, but outside of downtown, and telling them that all of your is actually in the downtown area.  Outside of that specific situation *I work downtown* is most likely what you want to say.